# File path error Cannot open file, path = 'lib/assets/posts.csv' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Tags: flutter, csv, dart

Not sure exactly what's going wrong here, but I've added my assets directory in my project folder and added it to the pubspec.yaml but when I try to read the csv file it get the above error.

```
  final posts = File('assets/posts.csv').readAsLinesSync().map((lines) {
  final parts = lines.split(',');
  return Post(
    title: parts[0],
    numDownVotes: int.tryParse(parts[1]),
    numUpVotes: int.tryParse(parts[2]),
  );
}
).toList();
```

Comment: the issue is that the File() is meant to getting files from their relative or absolute paths, which means from the device, so either you will need to load that file using RootBundle..., or you will need to make another function which saves that asset file to the device then get it using File().

Answer (score 0):

How often and for what reason does the csv file get updated? Given that your code refers to down and up votes, I guess that it is changed often. In which case it is not an asset. The assets folder contains things that are incorporated into your app only when it is built. It is not used when you run the app, the csv file needs to be written to and read from the devices local storage....as @gwhyyy indicates.